# How do you change the selected value of a select input from the controller?

Tags: angularjs

My template:

```
<select ng-model="state" ng-options="state.name for state in states">
    <option value="">ALL</option>
</select>
```

My controller:

```
var stateList = [
  { name: 'ALABAMA', abbreviation: 'AL'},
  { name: 'ALASKA', abbreviation: 'AK'},
  { name: 'ARIZONA', abbreviation: 'AZ'},
  { name: 'ARKANSAS', abbreviation: 'AR'},
  ...
]

$scope.states = stateList;
$scope.state = 'ALL';  // Default

$scope.updateStateModel = function(state) {
  $scope.state = state.toUpperCase();  // Does nothing
};
```

The value of `$scope.state` does change but is not reflected on the `<select>` input. How do you properly bind it so that the value of `<select>` is in sync with `$scope.state` ?

Comment: Check that `$scope.states` contains the value you want to select

Comment: Can you show the context of your call to `updateStateModel(state)` ?

Comment: $scope.state must contain the state object to select. Not the state name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **ngModel** needs to be bound to the same object type, here's a working example:

**html:**

```
<div ng-app="App"  ng-controller="ctrl">
<select ng-model="state" ng-options="state.name for state in states">
    <option value="">ALL</option>
</select>
    <div ng-repeat="state in states"><span ng-click="updateStateModel(state)">{{state.name}}</span></div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
function ctrl($scope) {
        $scope.states = [{name:"aa"},{name:"bb"},{name:"cc"}];
    $scope.state = 'ALL';  // Default

    $scope.updateStateModel = function(state) {
      $scope.state = state; 
    };
 }
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/3RGpv/

Comment: Your answer alone was not enough. Apparently, `$scope.$apply()` also needs to be called.

Comment: Could that be necessary because I'm calling `updateStateModel()` from a child directive?

Comment: there is no need to work with apply, it just adds extra performance hit, you can easily add $scope.$parent.state=state , example :http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/3RGpv/4/